# calling rest API(locally running) from nodejs failed

Tags: java, python, node.js, rest, api

We created a rest API on python and it is locally running. And the 'http://127.0.0.1:5002/business' API is showing contents `{"business name": "something"}` if I open it on google chrome. However, when we call this API in nodejs, it always gives me the error. But if I use another API(exactly same code but different api in nodejs), it is working.

```js
  async function get_recommend_initial(){
    //https://ViolaS.api.stdlib.com/InitialRecommendation@dev/
    // // agent.add('providing recommendations...');
    const options = {
      method: 'GET'
      ,uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:5002/business'
      // ,uri:'https://ViolaS.api.stdlib.com/InitialRecommendation@dev/'
      // ,json: true
    };
    // return request(options).then(response => {
    //   console.log(response)
    //   return (response)
    // }).catch(function (err) {
    //         console.log('No recommend data');
    //         console.log(err);
    //       });
    return requestAPI(options).then(function(data)
    {
      let initial_recommendation = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(initial_recommendation);
      //return initial_recommendation.information[0].name;
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log('No recommend data');
      console.log(err);
    });
    
  }
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXraQ.png)
The API that is created by python file which is running locally. You can see the API code figure by moving your mouth above [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXraQ.png). Thanks!!!
The python code is as follows:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
#Add resources to be much cleaner
api = Api(app)

features = {}

class Business(Resource):

    def get(self):
        return {'business name': 'something'} # Fetches first column that is Employee ID

    def post(self):
        some_json  = request.get_json()
        print(some_json)
        countNumber = features.get('count',0) + 1
        features['count'] = countNumber
        return {'You sent': some_json,
               'Count:':countNumber}, 201
    def put(self):
        some_json  = request.get_json()
        print(some_json)
        #record the count number 
        countNumber = features.get('count',0) + 1
        features['count'] = countNumber
        features['ok'] = 'yes'
        return {'You sent': some_json,
               'Count:':countNumber,
               'Ok:': features['ok']}, 201


api.add_resource(Business, '/business') # Route_1

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port='5002')
```

The error is as following:

```
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment

Error: Unknown response type: "undefined" at WebhookClient.addResponse_ (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:277:13) at WebhookClient.add (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:245:12) at Sys_Recommend (/srv/index.js:31:11) at <anonymous>
```

And the log is:

```
No recommend data
```

Comment: Please add your Python code **as text**!

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for your suggestion, I added my python code.

Comment: @AZ_ I edited my post and added my error. Thanks!!